# Slow raid5 resync with WD Green drives

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid, mdadm, raid5

## The Question

Why is my initial resync so slow? Initially `cat /proc/mdstat` reported `~ 30000K/sec`.

- I then increased `/sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size` from `256` to `16384`. That increased the speed to `~50000K/sec`.
- I changed `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min` from `1000` to `100000` and `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max` from `200000` to `400000`, but that didn't help.

What else can I do to speed things up?

- [This topic](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1140705&sid=9a008d810311f4ddb8fac10434e9bdb3&start=40) suggests replacing Western Digital Green drives with anything different. That is not an option for me.
- Running `smartctl -t short /dev/sd[bcd]` and later `smartctl -l selftest /dev/sd[bcd]` did not reveal any errors.
- A number of resources that I found on the topic ([1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1615374), [2](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html)) are not very specific about how (which commands) to change certain settings, not do they explain very well what they do & why they help.

## Some Background

### How I set up the raid array

I just added three 2TB Western Digital SATA (their "green" series) drives to my Ubuntu 14.04 server. They are `/dev/sd[bcd]`.

I decided to use them in a raid5 array and set everything up like this:
**1) Create one partition on each disk:**
`fdisk /dev/sdb` (same for `sdc` and `sdd`)

Based on [this blog post](http://blog.webvict.im/2012/09/24/linux-software-raid-with-western-digital-wd20ears-green-drives/) I chose `2048` and `3907029128` as the respective first and last sector on each disk. These numbers are divisible by 4, since these drives are 4K sector drives.

The fs type was set to `da (Non-FS data)`, as per that blog post, which reads

> This stops distribution auto-mount startup scripts for searching for superblocks on drives marked as “fd” and trying to mount them up in a funny order.

Since the raid array is non-essential for booting up the system, that makes sense to me.

**2) create raid array using `mdadm`:**
`mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --chunk=2048 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 --spare-devices=0 --force`

The `--chunk=2048` option was also inspired by the [same blog post](http://blog.webvict.im/2012/09/24/linux-software-raid-with-western-digital-wd20ears-green-drives/), "bear[ing] in mind the 'should be divisible by 4' logic."

The `--spare-devices=0 --force` options are my own creation, since without them the `mdadm` command would start the inital resync process, but quickly slow down to `< 200K/sec`, and then bail out with a message in `/var/mail/root` that `/dev/sdd` "might have failed". After that happening, the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` would show that `/dev/sdd1` had been moved to be a spare drive.
Since adding these options, the resync is continued running. It first slowed down to `< 100K/sec` but then speed increased to about `30000K/sec` and stayed there.

### About the running resync process

**`atop` reveals that `/dev/sdd` is the slowest**

```
DSK |          sdd  | busy    103% | read     930  | write    304 | KiB/r    512  |              |  KiB/w    512 | MBr/s  46.50 |  MBw/s  15.20 | avq   112.12 |  avio 8.10 ms |
DSK |          sdc  | busy     85% | read     942  | write    384 | KiB/r    508  |              |  KiB/w    410 | MBr/s  46.75 |  MBw/s  15.40 | avq    20.59 |  avio 6.21 ms |
DSK |          sdb  | busy     73% | read     942  | write    387 | KiB/r    508  |              |  KiB/w    411 | MBr/s  46.75 |  MBw/s  15.55 | avq    17.31 |  avio 5.31 ms |
```

### About the WD Green drives

All drives were bought at a different time (so I suspect they're from different production runs, months apart).
`/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` are the youngest and have 64MB cache. `/dev/sdd` has 32MB cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only minutes after posting this question, the initial resync cancelled itself again by moving the oldest of my disks to a "spare" location, before even hitting 100%.

Even though the device did not reveal any `smartclt` issues, it turned out that it was in fact broken. This was established by `badblocks`, which revealed thousands of broken sectors.
Replacing that disk with a new one fixed the issue for me.